# Large MySQL data (90GB) migration

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to migrate large mysql database to old centOS server to new centOS server. mysql file size has been more than 90GB.I have tried mysql migration tool to transfer all data but it takes long time. what is the best method to transfer all data to the new server ?

Comment: You could just stop the service, copy the whole MySQL folder to the new server then edit the `my.ini/cnf` file in the new server to refer data from the copied folder.

Comment: This is not a programming question ...

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with MySQL databases much larger than 90GB.

Use [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup) to make a hot, physical backup of the source database. This is much faster than creating a data dump.

Then transfer the backup to the new server, use it to overwrite the data directory of a MySQL instance there (which must be stopped), fix up the file permissions if necessary, and then start mysqld. Done! You can migrate the mysql database as quickly as you can `scp` the files over the network.

You may also like to configure the new instance as a replication client temporarily, so you can sync it up with the most recent changes in the source database that occurred after you made the backup.

The detailed steps for this process are found here: https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/latest/howtos/setting_up_replication.html